# Combinatorial Game Theory resources

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

Can you refer me to some Combinatorial Game Theory books, which contains problems with solutions? I couldn't find anything on Amazon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A gentle introduction by one of the giants is *Fair Game*, by Richard Guy. See https://www.comap.com/product/?idx=1366 (where it can be ordered for \$12.95 -- Amazon wants over \$100 for it!) It has exercises and answers.

Answer (score -1):

The bible: [Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/winning-ways-for-your-mathematical-plays-volume-1) (in 4 volumes) by Elwyn R. Berlekamp, John H. Conway and Richard K. Guy.

Comment: I would not recommend Winning Ways to someone looking for a textbook with exercises and solutions. It doesn't generally present exercises and solutions and its informal style can be harder for someone new to work with.